# Arima.sim issues in R

Tags: r, math, statistics, time-series, forecasting

I am working on making a prediction in R using time-series models.
I used the auto.arima function to find a model for my dataset (which is a ts object).
`fit<-auto.arima(data)`
I can then plot the results of the prediction for the 20 following dates using the forecast function:

```
plot(forecast(fit,h=20))
```

However I would like to add external variables and I cannot do it using forecast because it is kind of a black box to me as I am new to R.
So I tried to mimic it by using the arima.sim function and a problem arose:
HOW TO INITIALIZE THIS FUNCTION ?
I got the model by setting `model=as.list(coef(fit))` but the other parameters are still obscure to me.
I went through hundreds of page including in stackoverflow but nobody seems to really know what is going on.
How is it calculated ? Like why does n.start (the burn-in period) must have ma+ar length and not only a max(ar,ma) length ? What is exactly start.innov?
I thought I understood when there is only an AR part but I cannot reproduce the results with an AR+MA filter.
My understanding as for the AR is concerned is that start.innov represent the errors between a filtered zero-signal and the true signal, is it true ?
Like if you want to have an ar of order 2 with initial conditions (a1,a2) you need to set

```
start.innov[1]=a1-ar1*0-ar2*0=a1 

start.innov[2]=a2-ar1*start.innov[1]
```

and innov to `rep(0,20)` but what to do when facing an arima function how do you set the innov to get exactly the same curbs as forecast does ?
thanks for your help !!!

Comment: format your question so become readable?

Comment: Sorry it is actually my first post on Stack so beginner mistake !

Comment: please help me with my question:
[I need help, i need simulate a arima in R][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918632/i-need-help-i-need-simulate-a-arima-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused between modelling and simulation. You are also wrong about `auto.arima()`.

`auto.arima()` *does* allow exogenous variables via the `xreg` argument. Read the help file. You can include the exogenous variables for future periods using `forecast.Arima()`. Again, read the help file.

It is not clear at all why you are referring to `arima.sim()` here. It is for simulating ARIMA processes, not for modelling or forecasting.

Comment: Thank you sir for your quick answer, I did not know how to include external variables with forecast.arima so I tried to do it by hand with arima.sim, which is nice because it can give you better understanding of what is done. I am not confused between modelling and simulating, I am confused in how you forecast using a model that you have (how forecast works).

Comment: My understanding is once you have the model of your signal (with auto.arima for instance)you use the last values of your signal and the last errors and filter it using you arima filter to get the next value and then again. I would be so glad if you could help me do it with arima.sim or explain to me how you do it with forecast. But your arima functions seem to work really well thank you for your work in R !

Comment: Please tell me if my understanding is completely off or not !
In the mean time I am going to use forecast.Arima instead but I would like to do it with arima.sim too.

Comment: I am really a beginner in R I guess saying forecast has no input parameters is not true and I apologize for that (I just found out that you could add other parameters) but the truth is every complicated function in R is a bit of a black box for the beginners like me !

Comment: Ok I will now make my question more precise : in the forecast function do you use the same model that you got using auto.arima and then simulate the next points using a function like arima.sim or is it more complex like Kalman filtering or etc.
If the answer is only using the likes of arima.sim I would very much like to learn how you would do it

Comment: Yes, the forecast function uses the model obtained by auto.arima. No, it does not use simulation for forecasting. Read a textbook such as http://www.otexts.org/fpp/8

Comment: I have already read this website, which was really helpful, I must apologize again for my clumsiness and my lack of knowledge but it does seem to be as the method you describe in [link](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/8) could be obtained by filtering the right initial conditions (the last values of the signal and the last innovations) and adding the right innovations (not adding some random values using rand.gen for instance which would be simulation) which could be done using arima.sim, It is maybe incorrect to call that simulation it is more like filtering.

Comment: I actually know how to do predictions (maybe biased I dont know) with only an AR part (by setting all innovations at 0 and choosing the right start.innov) but when you add the MA part I am at a loss. That was my initial question : do you think it is possible ? Can you send me links to other as intersting webpages? But again thank you for your time !